# "Function name must be a string" on INSERT - mysqli PHP

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, syntax-error

I have puzzled over this for some time. It is puzzling because a very similar query just a few lines above works fine. I am very new to mysqli, so there may be something very fundamental I am missing.
The connection is set up like this:

```
   Class dbObj{
      /* Database connection start */
      var $servername = "myserver";
      var $username = "myusername";
      var $password = "mypassword";
      var $dbname = "mydb";
      var $conn;

      function getConnstring() {
          $con = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

          /* check connection */
          if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
              exit();
          } else {
              $this->conn = $con;
          }
          return $this->conn;
      }
    }
```

Then, in an Ajax processing file:

```
include_once({the connection file above});
$db = new dbObj();
$connString =  $db->getConnstring();
$params = $_REQUEST;
$action = isset($params['action']) != '' ? $params['action'] : '';
$NeedsCls = new Needs($connString);
```

Then, inside a class called "Needs":

```
   protected $conn;
   protected $data = array();
   function __construct($connString)
  {
       $this->conn = $connString;
   }
   function insertNeeds($params)
   {
       $ExpDate = $params[Expire];
       $sql = "INSERT INTO `pNeeds` (PubCode, Title, Description, Keywords, Expire) VALUES('".$_SESSION["PubCode"]."','".$params["Title"]."','".$params["Description"]."','".$params[NeedsTags]."','".$ExpDate."'); ";
       echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("Error - Failed inserting Needs data");
     $Record = $db->insert_id;
     $KW = explode(';',$params[NeedsTags]);
     $KWCount = count($KW);
     for($x=0;$x<$KWCount;$x++)
     {
        $Keyword = $KW[$x];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `Keywords` (Keyword, PubCode, Table, Record, Expire) VALUES ('".$Keyword."','".$_SESSION["PubCode"]."','pNeeds','".$Record."','".$ExpDate."'); ";
        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql) or die("Error - Keywords not saved<br />".$mysqli_error());
     }
  }
```

The first query works fine. The second fails with the error "Function name must be a string". I've verified the data going into the Ajax code is correct. It doesn't appear that I am missing something stupid. (famous last words) The error message makes no sense to me. Similar posts here on StackOverflow and elsewhere do not seem to pertain in this instance.

Comment: Be sure and give this a pass checking for SQL injection attacks at some point before it goes live. I'm sure this is just early code but just in case, concatenating those user-controlled params directly into your SQL leaves you wide open. (Use prepared statements/bound params instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just grabbing $params wrong:

```
$ExpDate = $params[Expire];
$params[NeedsTags];
```

Should be:

```
$ExpDate = $params['Expire'];
$params['NeedsTags'];
```

**Edit**

You're actual error is from:

```
$mysqli_error()
```

Remove the `$`

**Edit**
RationalRabbit: To avoid confusing anyone, I should mention that the whole syntax was wrong. Using object oriented mysqli, the error syntax should have been

```
 db->error
```

OR

```
mysqli($this->conn)
```

Comment: That IS an oversight, because I usually do try to quote them, but is there some reason this would make a difference to mysqli? Also, please note, as I stated, the first query works fine, so it doesn't look like that is the problem.

Comment: It's not related to MySqli at all, if you're trying to access a variable inside an array, you need to use the square braces with the quotes.

Comment: The query could just as well be written like this. It would still work. $sql = "INSERT INTO pNeeds (PubCode, Title, Description, Keywords, Expire) VALUES('$_SESSION[PubCode]','$params[Title]','$params[Description]','$params[NeedsTags]','$ExpDate')";

Comment: Well give us the line the error is coming from. I've just suggested the most glaringly obvious answer that **can cause** the error you're seeing.

Comment: What line? The SECOND query that has the function $mysqli_error()); at the end of it, which is what produces the error.message

Comment: Ok well it was also a simpler error than I anticipated. Remove the `$` from `$mysqli_error()`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your points may still be valid depending what you're accessing in the `$params` variable, but yes we were both looking at the wrong spot.. haha

Comment: LOL! Can't believe I did that! Thank you.

Comment: And I can't believe I quoted it and STILL didn't notice it!

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Good luck with the app.

Comment: And then, I was STILL wrong. See my addition to your edit.